# How to bind a local address as the source address while using Ganymed API to SFTP?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, ssh2-sftp

We are deploying a Java project on Linux Server. A file is generated by the project which is then sent to a remote server.

It was earlier implemented using Jsch. However, due to its dependency on JCE and the inability to upgrade the java version (from 5) we are switching to Ganymed. I am using Ganymed build 210 (viz. is tested for java 5; http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2)

This is the function I am using to sftp the file.

```
public boolean sftp_put() {

    File privateKeyFile = new File(identityPath);
    File rfile = new File(hostDir);
    File lfile = new File(lpath);
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        if (!lfile.exists() || lfile.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException("Local file must be a regular file: "
                    + lpath);
        }

        Connection ssh = new Connection(host, port);

        ssh.connect();

        ssh.authenticateWithPublicKey(user, privateKeyFile, password);
        SFTPv3Client sftp = new SFTPv3Client(ssh);

        try {
            SFTPv3FileAttributes attr = sftp.lstat(hostDir);
            if (attr.isDirectory()) {
                rfile = new File(hostDir, lfile.getName());
            }
        } catch (SFTPException e) {
            try {
                SFTPv3FileAttributes attr = sftp.lstat(rfile.getParent());
                if (!attr.isDirectory()) {
                    throw new IOException(
                            "Remote file's parent must be a directory: "
                                    + hostDir + "," + e);
                }
            } catch (SFTPException ex) {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Remote file's parent directory must exist: "
                                + hostDir + "," + ex);
            }
        }
        SFTPv3FileHandle file = sftp.createFileTruncate(rfile
                .getCanonicalPath());

        long fileOffset = 0;
        byte[] src = new byte[32768];
        int i = 0;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(lfile);
        while ((i = input.read(src)) != -1) {
            sftp.write(file, fileOffset, src, 0, i);
            fileOffset += i;
        }

        input.close();
        sftp.closeFile(file);
        sftp.close();

        success=true;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        logger.warn("Exception while trying to sftp", e)
    }

    return success;
}
```

I am unable to connect to the remote server possibly due to binding issues and unsure on how to proceed? I am thinking on binding a local address before the SFTP.

So I wrote a socket function.

```
public Socket createSocket(String destinationHost, int destinationPort)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    logger.info("sftp configured bind address : " + bindAddress
            + ", bind port : " + bindPort);
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(bindAddress, bindPort));
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(destinationHost, destinationPort),
            connectionTimeOut);
    if (socket.isBound()) {
        logger.info("sftp actual bind port : " + socket.getLocalPort());
    } else {
        logger.warn("sftp socket not bound to local port");
    }
    return socket;
}
```

However this is also not working, and I am getting a Socket Exception.

EDIT: So I was creating the socket in the right way but no where am I using the same socket for creating the connection. Such a method is not defined in any of the Ganymed libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was not an inherent method in ganymed, I edited the source code to write a method.

Following are the edits I made.

to the class where I am using

```
SocketAddress sourceAddress = new InetSocketAddress(bindAddress,
                bindPort);
        Connection ssh = new Connection(host, port);
        ssh.bindSourceAddress(sourceAddress);
        ssh.connect();
```

then I made some changes to connection.class of Ganymed API. Imported class and declared variables accordingly

This is the simple method for passing the bindAddress.

```
public void bindSourceAddress(SocketAddress sourceAddress) {
            this.sourceAddress = sourceAddress;
        }
```

Passing the address to Transport Manager class when initialize method is used.

```
if (sourceAddress != null) {
                tm.initialize(cryptoWishList, verifier, dhgexpara,
                        connectTimeout, getOrCreateSecureRND(), proxyData,
                        sourceAddress);
            } else {
                tm.initialize(cryptoWishList, verifier, dhgexpara,
                        connectTimeout, getOrCreateSecureRND(), proxyData);
            }
```

Modified the constructor of initialize method. It in turn calls an establish connection function, which is similarly modified to accomodate SocketAddress.

```
private void establishConnection(ProxyData proxyData, int connectTimeout, SocketAddress sourceAddress) throws IOException
{
    /* See the comment for createInetAddress() */

    if (proxyData == null)
    {
        InetAddress addr = createInetAddress(hostname);
        //test
        if (sourceAddress != null) {
                            sock.bind(sourceAddress);
                        }
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, port), connectTimeout);
        sock.setSoTimeout(0);
        return;
    }

    if (proxyData instanceof HTTPProxyData)
    {
        HTTPProxyData pd = (HTTPProxyData) proxyData;

        /* At the moment, we only support HTTP proxies */

        InetAddress addr = createInetAddress(pd.proxyHost);
        //test
        if (sourceAddress != null) {
                            sock.bind(sourceAddress);
                        }
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, pd.proxyPort), connectTimeout);
        sock.setSoTimeout(0);
```

Finally bound the socket. Being a java Novice it took me my own sweet time to get this right. No one will most probably read this or need it, but posted this solution just in case for someone like me!